# How register and login in django in same time with class based views?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple registration view, i want to create a view can register user and login him at same time.
my code not working,
what should do i do to do it?
my views.py:

```py
class user_register(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView,):
    model = User
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("company:home")
    form_class = UserRegisterationForm 
    success_message = "You registered successfully."
    def form_valid(self,form):
        user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),password=form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        if user is not None:
                login(self.request,user)
                return redirect('company:home')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: First calling `super().form_valid(form)` and then write your code.

Comment: Unfortunately , after i ran it , i got AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error.

Comment: I have updated my answer. When you save the form you don't need to invoke authentication as you already provide a backend when you call login().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to save your object.

Model form views provide a [form_valid()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) implementation that saves the model automatically or simple save your form.

So call first `form.save()`.

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    user = form.save()
    login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
    return redirect('company:home')
```

Comment: ty. but request in form must be ```self.request```

Comment: @NIMAZ, Yeap !